Typing Pydantic mutated @field_validator property
Consider the following Pydantic class:
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator

class UserAttributes(BaseModel):
    user_groups: list[str]
    ...

    @field_validator("user_groups", mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def make_user_group_list(cls, user_groups: str) -> list[str]:
        if not user_groups:
            raise ValueError("User groups cannot be empty")
        return user_groups.replace(" ", "").split(",")

As the function suggests, user_groups is a comma separated list e.g. "Admin, User", which the validator transforms into an array, e.g. ["Admin", "User].
The problem now is, when I use the class, like so:
request = UserAttributes(user_groups="Admin, User") # type: ignore

Type checking obviously wants it to be an array.
Is there a way in which I can type the pydantic class correctly, without me having to do "hacky" tricks to make it work? (Such hacky tricks could be creating an intermediate property, which has a field validator that writes to user_groups=

Easiest would probably be using a Union[str, List[str] but this might open up other issues. Why not simply feed the constructor the correct type in the first place, like UserAttributes(user_groups="Admin, User".split(", "))?

You could pass it from a dict  UserAttributes(**dict(user_groups="user,admin") or use UserAttributes.model_validate(dict(user_groups="user,admin")).  Using the first approach you can still get type hints for the other params. I don't think that there is a way to annotate the type in the way you want to.

I have the same case on a project of mine, but I created 2 classes one that would represent the table model and the other that would represent the schema. in the schema I have it as a list and use a field validator. It depends on your usage, but like @RolandDeschain suggested I would pass the correct type

You could also add a factory class method instead of the field validator, like FromString(user_groups: str) and FromList(user_groups: List[str]) which do the transformation and return an instance of the class. Not sure if this would fit your codebase.
